# NextJS / Firebase. Unexpected display

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting

In order to test and review the process of creating an app with NextJS and Firebase, I created a test app using the following commands:

```
 % npx create-next-app@latest
    -> app name: myapp
 % cd myapp
```

Then I edited the next.config.mjs file to make it look like:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export'
};

export default nextConfig;
```

Then I ran this command:

```
 % firebase init hosting
```

I used the default options as much as possible when running the above commands.

Except for:

```
What do you want to use as your public directory?
I answered: out
```

This is how I set the app/page.tsx file:

```
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <div>My App</div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

In order to access the app with its own URL: https://myapp.web.app/
instead of the project standard URL, I add this line to the firebase.json file.
(right next to the "public": ... line)

```
"site": "myapp",
```

At this point I can run:

```
 % npm run dev
```

and see the expected display in the browser at http://localhost:3000/.

```
  My App
```

I can also run these commands to see the expected display at : https://myapp.web.app/.

```
 % npm run build
 % firebase deploy --only hosting
```

Then I want to set up some dynamic routes.

For that inside the app directory, I create:

```
app/members/[mbrId]/page.tsx
```

with the following contents:

```
import React from "react";

interface pageProps {
        params: {
                mbrId: string
        }
}

type Member = {
        mbrId: string
}

export default function MemberPage({params: {mbrId}}: pageProps) {
        return <div>MemberPage for {mbrId}</div>
} /* End of MemberPage */
```

If I run:

```
 % npm run dev
```

at this point the dynamic route is not working.

After running this:

```
 % touch next.config.js
```

it works locally as expected.

This is when I want to make dynamic routes work server side that issues start to raise.

I have added this block inside the "hosting" section of the firebase.json file:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/members/**",
    "destination":"/members/[mbrId]/index.html"
  }
]
```

and also tried:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "regex": "^/members/([^/]+?)(?:/)?$",
    "destination":"/members/[mbrId]/index.html"
  }
]
```

But running:

```
 % npm run build
 % firebase deploy --only hosting
```

and looking at: https://myapp.web.app/members/HD88BX22
displays:

```
404
This page could not be found.
```

instead of displaying the expected:

```
MemberPage for HD88BX22
```

As it did when looking at:

```
http://localhost:3000/members/HD88BX22
```

These are the tool versions I am using:

```
 % node --version
v20.11.0
 % npm --version
10.2.4
 % firebase --version
13.2.0
"next": "14.1.0"
```

Comment: You are trying to run npm run build which is not supported for firebase hosting beacuse it depends on node.js environment you could use next statix export for app directory OR you could checked out the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/nextjs)

Comment: @AL_Faiz_Ahmed. I want to take a close look at the docs you mention. Concerning "next static export", after doing some research it seems that this is mostly what I was already doing, maybe in the wrong order. Anyway, I tried again and made some progress, but could not make dynamic routes work server side. I made significant change to my original post to reflect the current situation. If you have time please take a look and let me know what you think or notice.

Comment: @AL_Faiz_Ahmed. I also started to work from the docs you mention. It works quite well. I hope that it will not break apart (experimental).

Comment: @Micel Dynamic Routes could also acheive with static params function just do a little more research 